# Bootable 12.04 USB drive failing due to "Filesystem cannot be mounted..." error?

Tags: installation, grub2, windows

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 from a bootable USB drive to my OCZ 256GB SSD, and have had nothing but problems. At first it was hanging at a black screen but then, following some directions I found on another askubuntu.com questions, I set `console=tty1` as a boot option and saw at what point the installation process was freezing:

[image: http://ubuntuone.com/1rIpvMcDbtmTPMs3lKL7qQ (warning, large image)]

I have this issue using the 32- or 64-bit image. I have downloaded the ISOs multiple times in case I had a corrupted image. I have tried creating bootable USB drive on another Ubuntu machine using both usb-creator and unetbootin; I have also tried creating it on Windows using LinuxLive USB creator (same thing as usb-creator on linux) and unetbootin as well.

My PC is a UEFI system, if it's relevant.

I am very confused since I have installed Ubuntu 11+ from USB many, many times and have never had an issue. How do I resolve this issue? My only recourse right now is to run Ubuntu inside a virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try [disabling (U)EFI](http://jurajsplayground.com/2012/08/24/ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin-failing-to-boot-because-of-uefi/).

I'm now trying to install 12.04 on an OCZ 60GB drive from a USB stick, downloaded ISO was correct (I md5sumed it).

However, the installation fails saying that the disk is corrupt. The disk check within the installer menu also says there is a problem with a file. Installing 12.04 32bit from a DVD worked.